# CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm having some issues with re-positioning some HTML elements using CSS, I'm trying to move some images on a word press template... however, they refuse to budge. The relevant CSS code is as below:

**I'm trying to move the social media images in the footer to match the body's padding.
I don't know how to do a JS Fiddle with PHP.**

Any help you can provide would be appreciated!

```
 /* THISIS: Social icons */
ul.social-media{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
ul.social-media li{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin: 7px 8px 7px 8px;
}
ul.social-media li a{
    width: 16px;
    display:block;
    height: 16px;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    padding:12px;
    background-position:left top;
    background-color:#e3e3e3;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}ul.social-media li a.facebook{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/facebook.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.twitter{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/twitter.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.rss{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/rss.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.google-plus{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/google.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.skype{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/skype.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.dribbble{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/dribbble.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.twitch{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/twitch.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.vimeo{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/vimeo.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.linked-in{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/linkedin.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.reddit{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/reddit.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.wordpress{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/wordpress.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a.youtube{
    background-image: url('../img/contact-icons/youtube.png');
    padding-right:10%;
}
ul.social-media li a:hover{
    background-position:0px -40px;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: you're going to need to post your HTML or better yet: a link or a fiddle

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Money? WP developers?

Comment: Can you copy some of the site code with Inspector and include that as well so that we can see how things are interconnected?

Comment: Try being more specific about what your looking to accomplish. You can move elements with css in many many different ways, the code block you pasted isn't very useful without more information.

Comment: restate your question so that the issue can be well understood

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve but the following CSS properties are those you should play with: position / margin / padding / display / left / right / top / bottom

For example try

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
margin-left: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use property margin instead of padding, or you can set position: relative, absolute or set float: left, right for elements you want to change position. Can you detail your html files or any plunkers (online examples)?